# Convert Docker image into binary on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, docker, executable, binaryfiles

Suppose I have a Docker image that runs some fun, but horrendously-complicated-to-compile-on-Mac-OSX-for audio editing application that does specific rendering of audio in realtime.

I have a Docker setup that runs this decently with a Linux image, but the process of getting audio piped to the host system isn't reliable nor performant. I'd really like to just run it directly on the host OS.

I'd like to run this desktop application nicely on Mac, but not have dependencies on Docker, Wine, etc.

Is there a way to make a single binary out of a Docker image that runs natively on Mac OSX?

I assume it would have to depend on some dynamic libs that Docker has, but that's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.

Consider that even the "native" Docker Desktop for Mac application actually works with a hidden virtual machine.  (Compare the outputs of `uname -a` and `docker run --rm busybox uname -a`, for example.)  That's why you're able to run Linux containers on a MacOS host.  But that also means that, if you were able to package up a Linux container into something that could run directly, it'd have to bring the rest of the Linux VM with it.

There are tools like [Packer](https://packer.io) that can help with the process of building a VM, but you'll hit the same issues you're already encountering on connecting the VM's display/audio to the host's.  Simplifying or automating the native-application build process is probably a better time investment.

Comment: Yes, completely agree. And it certainly wouldn't be easier than say: figuring out how to compile that very complicated thing for OSX

Comment: OK, makes sense. Looks like there isn''t a shortcut! thanks everyone